# Django + postgreSQL. user specific table

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

I am currently working on a Django based service that will gather users' data from their Shopify shops and provide some insights. I use PostgreSQL as my DB server. The problem I am facing is whether it is more efficient to create a separate table for every particular user and store their data there or rather keep everything in one big table. Approximate data length - about 100k-1mln rows per user. Data is unrelated among users. Furthermore, I will need to store the user-specific results of my analysis. Any thoughts?

Comment: No, don't make a new table per user.

Comment: sounds like you are a bit out of the league here, I suggest reading up on this --> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form

Comment: How do you end up with one million rows of data for a single user?

Comment: If you're on that scale and have loads of users then perhaps it does make sense for each user to have their own table but, potentially, a) something could be very wrong with your approach or b) you need a different technology to scale to this.

Comment: roganjosh, let me make it more clear. Every user has that many records in her Shopify stores. I am mostly interested in transactions. So you can imagine an average store having about 100 a day. If, say, I have 1000 users with 100k transactions, is it scalable enough to put everything (all transaction data) in a single table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Gleb: you commented on my other answer:

> But may we consider a more specific example: I have a user table which stores all user-related data, from every user I gather additional data to analyse (transactions). So I was thinking of creating a new table for every user and store there transactions data, the name of the table will be stored in table1 (where I keep info about my users) to locate it when needed. Should I keep transactions of all users in one table?

So here goes a more concrete example.

---

For starters, you have your `User` model (maybe even djangos default table) where you store attributes like names and email.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Second, you have transactions (I made up a few basic fields):

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    # default AutoField as pk
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()
    user_from = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='transactions_from')
    user_to = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='transactions_to')
    amount = models.IntegerField()
```

And third, you could have a monthly summary of transactions to sum up the received and sent amounts of each user:

```
class Summary(models.Model):
    # default AutoField as pk
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    year = models.IntegerField()
    month = models.IntegerField()
    amount_sent = models.IntegerField()
    amount_received = models.IntegerField()
```

---

Now, the `Transaction` model will have a lot of records (you say it could have millions per user), but the `Summary` model will only have one record per month per user, which is quite manageable.
Still, I don't recommend using a separate model/table of transactions for each user.

Once a month you could run a process that calculates the summaries for each user (or any other data analysis you wish to run) if you don't wish to update the `Summary` model instance each time a new transaction is made.

Afterwards you are free to archive the old `Transactions` (maybe everything older than 3 months or a year).
Once a month you could run a process to export a given set of `Transaction` instances to a file (CSV, JSON or a SQL dump) and remove them from the `Transaction` model to keep the size of the table from expanding to much. You could obtain backup files per month for easier lookup if you ever need the `Transaction` data again:

```
backup_transaction_2018_01.sql
backup_transaction_2018_02.sql
backup_transaction_2018_03.sql
```

I hope this gives you a few ideas to think about.

Comment: Thanks @Ralf. May the force to be with you)

Comment: @Gleb +1 for the Star Wars reference (even though its still May 3rd in my timezone)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have one big table (`Table1`) for the data of all users (one column would indicate which user it belongs to). 
For example, to store all the pages a user visited on one of your sites, you could use something like this:

```
Table1
    pk   # maybe automatic id
    user_id
    datetime
    page_url
    query_string
    some_session_data
```

If `Table1` gets too big (like you indicated that it may happen), you could create periodical backups with date ranges (maybe one backup file with data from a single month of `Table1` rows) and later delete the older data from `Table1`.

```
backup_table1_2018_01.sql
backup_table1_2018_02.sql
backup_table1_2018_03.sql
```

---

Furthermore, you could have a second table (`Table2`) that stores results of analysing the data from `Table1`. `Table2` would also have a column indicating which user it belongs to, and maybe even another column which indicates what date range it belongs to.

Continuing with the example, you could create a ranking to see the most visited page for each user in a single month:

```
Table2
    pk   # maybe automatic id
    user_id
    year
    month
    page_url
    number_of_visits
```

After calculating the results for `Table2` you could remove the rows from `Table1` to save some space.

---

This may be a silly/simple example, but I think it could be a valid approach for large amount of data. I hope it gives you some pointers to think about.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But may we consider a more specific example: I have a user table which stores all user-related data, from every user I gather additional data to analyse (transactions). So I was thinking of creating a new table for every user and store there transactions data, the name of the table will be stored in table1 (where I keep info about my users) to locate it when needed. Should I keep transactions of all users in one table?

Comment: @Gleb I don't want to add even more text to my answer, so I added a new answer with the concrete example you described.